# synchronize sharepoint documents with another system

Tags: sharepoint, jakarta-ee

Is it possible for the documents (inside the sharepoint document library)
to be accessible from another system library (implemented in J2ee), and both
should be synchronized together ?

Is this possible using "Microsoft Sync Framework for SharePoint" , then
using "webservices" to connect to the java API ?

May anyone give  me brief descriptions how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the documents inside a document library using the Server/Client Object Model or WebServices.

- [Download a file using the Server Object Model](http://avinashkt.blogspot.com/2009/11/code-to-download-document-from.html)
- [Upload a file using the Client Object Model](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/12/programmatically-upload-document-using-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/)
- [Get ListItemChanges WebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getlistitemchangeswithknowledge.aspx#Y0)

Please explain what you want to achieve (architecture) so it will be easier for us to understand and give you hints in the right direction.

Comment: Thank a lot Andreas.

I have an online system implemented in J2EE. Within this system there is a space for keeping the documents of the customers. I want to be able able to access my sharepoint documents also from my J2EE website (without the need to open the page of sharepoint). (i.e: I see the sharepoint documents on my J2EE website) 

How is this possible ?

Thanks in advance...